# How to validate several TextView field with infromation before going into the next activity

Tags: android, textview

What I am trying to do is check if all the TextView and Spinner(Drop down) have been filled and selected before going into the next activity. If any or some of them are empty I want to highlight the respective field. Any suggestions or help coding would be great.
I have something like this:

```
        value_1=tv1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        value_2=tv2.getText().toString();
        value_3=tv3.getText().toString();
        value_4=tv4.getText().toString();
        value_5=tv5.getText().toString(); 
        Intent intent= new Intent(FormActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key1",value_1);
        intent.putExtra("key2",value_2);
        intent.putExtra("key3",value_3);
        intent.putExtra("key4",value_4);
        intent.putExtra("key5",value_5);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a view

```
private View focusView = null;
```

OnClick of button call following method

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if (validate()) {
                   //do your work
                } else {
                    focusView.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

//code to validating each editext

```
   private boolean validate() {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getEmail)) {
            emailText.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = emailText;
            return false;
        } else if (!getEmail.matches(EMAIL_REGEX)) {
            emailText.setError("Invalid Email Address");
            focusView = emailText;         
            return false;
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getName)) {
               nameText.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = nameText;         
            return false;
        }
    else{
            return true;
        }
}
```

this will focus you view if particular edittext is empty and invalid

Comment: In this case the validate() only checks for the emailText, is there a way to check for all textview? I was thinking of putting them into a list and run into a for.

Comment: @jvargas you  can add more editText, I have done for only emailText, yo can add code for eg. nameText or passText etc etc

Comment: I can not get it, could you please show me how it would be with more than one field validation?

Comment: I did it that way before checking the answer, but it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your spinner problem look at the following tutorial.
[Spinnerdrop](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/)

That's a good tutorial. You need a listener to listen to a onclick method. Follow that and I think you will get there. If you need more help, feel free to ask

The following is for if you need to check whether a string is zero or not. 
The method length() wil return a int value of the length of the given string. In your case that value musn't become 0 (zero).

```
if((value_1.length() != 0 ) && (value_2.length() != 0) && (value_3.length() != 0) && (value_4.length() !=0) && (value_5.length() !=0))
{
    //Your code
} else {
   //handle error
}
```

**PS: Don't use android-studio tag, that's only for questions about the ide. Stick to android tag.**

Comment: I used this and worked, but what I want is to highlight the empty fields